# How to get a random value from truncated normal distribution with mean and std in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, normal-distribution

What is a JS alternative to the same Python implementation?

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.stats import truncnorm
import numpy as np
mean = 1
std = 2
clip_a = -4
clip_b = 3

a, b = (clip_a - mean) / std, (clip_b - mean) / std
x_range = np.linspace(-3 * std, 3 * std, 1000)
plt.plot(x_range, truncnorm.pdf(x_range, a, b, loc = mean, scale = std));
```

[image]

I'd like to get a random value according to the distribution (in JS the same code with `size=1`):

```
dist = truncnorm.rvs(a, b, loc = mean, scale = std, size=1000000)
plt.hist(dist);
```

[image]

Comment: To which python implementation exactly? The plotting of a graph?

Comment: @Bergi thanks for your help. No, not a graph. I ploted the graph for illustration purposes only. I'd like to get a random value according to the distribution. I showed a truncated normal distribution (this code can be copypasted to Colab) where user selects any value of `mean, std, clip_a` and `clip_b` and gets a random value.

Comment: @Bergi  Do you think it's impossible?

Comment: No, why would it be impossible? You can either search the web to find js libraries that are similar to `scipy.stats`, or you just take a look at their source code and re-implement it yourself in javascript.

Comment: I did not expect to find a JS one liner for this task but hoped not to do it from scratch.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a JS function that implements a truncated, skew-normal pseudo random number generator (PRNG). It is based on [this blog post](https://spin.atomicobject.com/2019/09/30/skew-normal-prng-javascript/) by Tom Liao and has been extended to consider lower and upper bounds (truncation).

Essentially, the function is called recursively until a variate within the desired bounds is found.
You can pass your own random number generator using the `rng` property, though `Math.random` will be used by default. Also, as you didn't ask for a skew-normal distribution, you can just ignore the skew property as it defaults to 0. This will leave you with a truncated normal PRNG, just as you asked for.

```js
function randomTruncSkewNormal({
  rng = Math.random,
  range = [-Infinity, Infinity],
  mean,
  stdDev,
  skew = 0
}) {
  // Box-Muller transform
  function randomNormals(rng) {
    let u1 = 0,
      u2 = 0;
    //Convert [0,1) to (0,1)
    while (u1 === 0) u1 = rng();
    while (u2 === 0) u2 = rng();
    const R = Math.sqrt(-2.0 * Math.log(u1));
    const Θ = 2.0 * Math.PI * u2;
    return [R * Math.cos(Θ), R * Math.sin(Θ)];
  }

  // Skew-normal transform
  // If a variate is either below or above the desired range,
  // we recursively call the randomSkewNormal function until
  // a value within the desired range is drawn
  function randomSkewNormal(rng, mean, stdDev, skew = 0) {
    const [u0, v] = randomNormals(rng);
    if (skew === 0) {
      const value = mean + stdDev * u0;
      if (value < range[0] || value > range[1])
        return randomSkewNormal(rng, mean, stdDev, skew);
      return value;
    }
    const sig = skew / Math.sqrt(1 + skew * skew);
    const u1 = sig * u0 + Math.sqrt(1 - sig * sig) * v;
    const z = u0 >= 0 ? u1 : -u1;
    const value = mean + stdDev * z;
    if (value < range[0] || value > range[1])
      return randomSkewNormal(rng, mean, stdDev, skew);
    return value;
  }

  return randomSkewNormal(rng, mean, stdDev, skew);
}
```

Calling this function in the following manner

```js
const data = [];
for (let i = 0; i < 50000; i++) {
  data.push({
    x: i,
    y: randomTruncSkewNormal({ 
      range: [-4,3], 
      mean: 1, 
      stdDev: 2
    })
  });
}
```

and plotting the data using your charting library of choice should give your the desired output.
[image: vega plot of truncated normal distribution]

I also made a [small Observable notebook](https://observablehq.com/@chrispahm/skew-normal-distributions) interactively demonstrating the function which you might want to check out as well.